# Meteor: populate a form select with objects from the mongo collection

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to make a page with a form which would include a select dropdown menu.  I'd like to have the select options come from the collection, rather than manually type them in the HTML.  So far no luck.  This is my code:

**html:**

```
<template name="addPage">
    <div id="addForm">
        <form>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>Select a genre:</label>
                    <select id = "genreList">
                        {{#each genres}}
                            {{> genre}}
                        {{/each}}
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Submit"></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="genre">
    <option value="{{genre}}">{{genre}}</option>
</template>
```

**js:** (Using mongodb-aggregation for the distinct call)

```
Template.addPage.genres = function () {

  Activities.distinct("genre", function(error, result){

    var returnArray = new Array();

    for(var i in result) {
      returnArray[i] = { 'genre': result[i] };
    }

    return returnArray;
  });
}
```

With this code, the select dropdown form is empty.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?

PS. I think perhaps the function Template.addPage.genres is returning before the array is filled...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the rendered callback:

```
Template.addPage.rendered = function() {
  Activities.distinct("genre", function(error, result){        
    result.sort();
    var genreList = document.getElementById('genreList');
    for(var i in result){
      var option=document.createElement("option");
      option.text=result[i];
      genreList.add(option, null);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this using Mongo's `find` method to expose the Collection to the template:

```
Template.addPage.genres = function() {
   return Genres.find({}, {sort:{time: -1}});       
}
```